# PHP encoding "les validations d'entr\u00e9es"

Tags: php, json, encoding

I have text in this format  `les validations d'entr\u00e9es` instead of `les validations d'entrées`.

This is from Twitter .json API and I would like to translate the `\u00e9` to the `é` but can't find a way to do it.

I suppose it's unicode so how can I translate those characters in PHP?

Sample of code that I already have:

```
 $this->jsonArray = json_decode($this->jsonData, true);
 //... Loop ...
 $output .=' <li class="twit">'.$this->jsonArray[$x]['text'] //....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_decode:

```
$raw = "{\"data\":\"les validations d'entr\u00e9es\"}";
var_dump(json_decode($raw));
```

Result:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'data' => string 'les validations d'entrées' (length=26)
```

Comment: I already have : $this->jsonArray = json_decode($this->jsonData, true);

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I thought it was Unicode but it was UTF8... Using the PHP method utf8_decode solve the problem. Thank you Eric to point me out the json_decode but it seems that it requires to have something more.

Comment: You can also convert the \uxxxxx references to HTML entities: `&#x00e9;` works too, but I don't entirely understand the logic behind it (which character set does this refer to?)

Comment: If you're getting mangled characters then there is an encoding issue.  The json_* functions work with utf8 data.  If you are expecting some other encoding then yes, you'll have to use something such as utf8_decode like you posted.  If you can, try moving towards a more progressive unicode environment.  There is a lot of info on this, so I won't repeat it here.  If you cannot do this I would recommend at a minimum using iconv with transliteration.

Comment: Thank Eric for the comment. I will accept your answer to give you some reputation. Thanks